# Error while making file sorting script

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that sorts my downloads; however, when I try to run it I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 538, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'UntitledDocument.txt' -> 'Downloads/TxtFiles/UntitledDocument.txt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nicholas/Python/DownloadSorter.py", line 19, in <module>
    shutil.move(file, folders[fileType])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 552, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 251, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 114, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'UntitledDocument.txt'
```

This is the code :
    #!/usr/bin/python3
    import os
    import shutil

```
folders = {
    '.tar.gz': 'Downloads/TarFiles',
    '.deb': 'Downloads/DebFiles',
    '.iso': 'Downloads/IsoFiles',
    '.txt': 'Downloads/TxtFiles',
    '.exe': 'Downloads/ExeFiles',
    '.mp3': 'Videos',
    '.wav': 'Music'
}
os.chdir('/home/nicholas/')

for file in os.listdir('Downloads'):
    for fileType in folders.keys():
        if file.endswith(fileType):
            shutil.move(file, folders[fileType])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the filename without the path and `shutil` looks for the file in the working directory intead of `Downloads` directory.

The fix is simple:

```
shutil.move(os.path.join('Downloads', file), folders[fileType])
```

Comment: ... Still assuming that the destination directory actually exists.

Comment: You are right. But we are dealing with it one error at a time :)